# How to make block inside table responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on Bootstrap. I wanted to make block inside table responsive.
As I resize the browser, block (bluebox) inside table is not adjusting according to screen size. I am new to Bootstrap.

[image]

```css
.bluebox
    {
        background-color: #F6F6FF;
        border: 1px solid #232850;
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow:hidden;
         min-width:267px;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
       overflow:auto;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
     <link type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
         <div class="page_info">
                     <div class="breadcrumb">
                         <a href="Default.aspx" style="font-size: 12px;color: #666;font-weight: 300;text-decoration: none;font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;">Home</a> 
                         <span class="delimiter fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></span> 
                         <span class="current" style="font-weight: 300;font-size: 12px;color: #666;">Link us</span></div> 
            <div class="page-title">
                        <h1 style="font-family: 'Roboto';font-size: 40px;line-height: 44px;color: #339933;font-weight: 300;">Link us</h1> 

            </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

        <p style="font-family:'Merriweather', sans-serif;font-size:16px;padding-left:18px;">To link to us, please choose and save one of the logos displayed below, and link it to ' http://www.dubaiexporters.com '.</p>

        <p style="font-family:'Merriweather', sans-serif;font-size:16px;padding-left:18px;">As per our linking Policy, no prior permission is required to link 'DubaiExporters.com' from your website. However, we would like you to inform us (using the 'Contact us' option) about any links provided to this Portal so that you can be informed of any changes or updates.</p>

        <p style="font-family:'Merriweather', sans-serif;font-size:16px;padding-left:18px;">We encourage you to choose from the following graphic banners which can be conveniently placed on your website and linked to our Portal.</p>

        <p><b style="color: #339933;padding-left:18px; font-size:20px;">Banners for Download </b></p>

        <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-left:18px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Banner</th>
        <th>Link</th>
       
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>         
            <a href="images/dubaiexportersbanners/dubaiexporters_168x72.gif" target="_blank"><img src="images/dubaiexportersbanners/dubaiexporters_168x72.gif" alt="dubaiexporters.com 130x38 jpg" width="168" height="72"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="bluebox">&lt;a href="http://www.dubaiexporters.com/"&gt;&lt;img src="http://www.dubaiexporters.com/images/dubaiexporters_168x72.gif" border="0" alt="Dubai Exporters - Directory of Exporters, Manufacturers &amp; Suppliers" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;</div>
        </td>
       
      </tr>
      
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Link:** https://jsfiddle.net/1h0bt35f/4/

Comment: It would be better to use [Media objects](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#media) instead of table.

Comment: You are limiting your `.bluebox` by giving `width:267px;` try: `width:100%`... Also have a look on https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: i tried that...https://jsfiddle.net/1h0bt35f/4/

Answer (score 1):

Update: Add `word-break: break-all;` to the CSS class.

Also, you would need to define width in percentage in order to make it responsive.

Currently, you have given bluebox a width of 267px.

Try the below code where you can set a min-width of 267px and it will handle automatically when it scales due to width as 100%.

```css
.bluebox {
  background-color: #F6F6FF;
  border: 1px solid #232850;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but i am getting the same result..when i resize it,the right side border of the table is not getting visible..even same with the border of bluebox...

Comment: Can you please create a sample app so that we can discuss more?

Comment: check the above link(jsfiddle)

Comment: I updated the code with another table at the bottom. The problem here is that the columns in your table are overflowing. Do you intend to keep them with a minimum width? The link is https://jsfiddle.net/1h0bt35f/9/

Comment: @Ankit...so i have to use max-width to td's?

Comment: I have further updated the code. https://jsfiddle.net/1h0bt35f/12/ , have added a property to bluebox to break words in order to wrap the contents. Let me know if it solves the issue now.

Comment: Most welcome, I have updated the answer with the correct change. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174224/discussion-between-chetan-kambli-and-ankit-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.bluebox
    {
        background-color: #F6F6FF;
        border: 1px solid #232850;
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow:hidden;
        width: 26%;
        display:block;
       overflow:auto;
    }
```

Comment: Giving a width of 267% will make the box overflow and it will eventually hide the contents of the box.

Comment: @Mandar the border of the bluebox is going out from the border of the table...i wanted to make the border of the blubox responsive as browser resizes